# Nested append in pug not appending

Tags: pug

I have the following scenario where my template is:

```
html(lang="en")
    head
        block head
            title= title
            block styles
                link(rel="stylesheet",href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

And my page is:

```
extends styles/template
block head
    title= "My Cool Title"
    append styles
        link(href="../styles/css/cover.css", rel="stylesheet")
```

If I were to place append styles in the same line as `block head`, then I'll receive an error that there's an unexpected block styles.

Despite having placed the append command, for some reason it overwrites all the items under style and appends the style I've specified. How would nested appends work in the case above?

I've looked through the documentation, and used `block append styles`, too. But no luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend, blocks are all flatten (no longer nested):

```
extends styles/template
block head
    title= "My Cool Title"
    block styles
        link(rel="stylesheet",href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css")

append styles
    link(href="../styles/css/cover.css", rel="stylesheet")
```

You must understand the process. When you do `block head`, you replace the whole block (loosing styles block if you do not recreate it).

So this is my recommendation for your case:

```
html(lang="en")
    head
        block head
            block title
                title= title
            block styles
                link(rel="stylesheet",href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

Then:

```
extends styles/template
block title
    title= "My Cool Title"
append styles
    link(href="../styles/css/cover.css", rel="stylesheet")
```

So the block head will not be touched.

Comment: I see. Basically have the title be a block that can be configured. That's a good solution. Thank you